# How does one Select All(*) in SFQL (Schema Free SQL)

Tags: sql, schema

If it is possible, how does one `Select All` `(*)` in [SFQL (Schema Free SQL)](http://schemafreesql.com/doc/sfql.html)

Comment: I've also tried creating a new tag but couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

I am the co-founder of SFSQL. We just released our V1 (only took us 7 years). You currently cannot select all Object attributes with a wild card but it is on the todo list.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the reference, I don't think `select *` is possible since you don't have joins. Of course even in regular SQL you never want to use `select *` anyway, as it is a SQL antipattern.

Comment: So far I could only *describe* de template and then query its fields. I am suspecting there isn't a way to `select all`, indeed.